# Displaying CSV Data in Table Format Below a Video using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am working on a project where I need to display a video along with corresponding data from a CSV file in a table format below the video.

The code reads the video and CSV file, and displays the video in a window. Below the video, it should show a table with the data from the CSV file. As the video progresses, the table data should be updated or scrolled up to match the timing in the video.

However, I am facing some issues with the code. The video is not playing properly, and the table rows are too big to see. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to fix these issues and improve the code.

Specifically, I would like to:

Ensure smooth video playback without freezing or buffering.
Adjust the table size to make it smaller and fit within the window properly.
Implement scrolling functionality for the table data to match the timing in the video.
Any help or guidance to resolve these issues and improve the code would be highly appreciated.

I have developed the following code using OpenCV and Python:

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Function to display video with CSV data in tabular format below the video
def display_video_with_csv(video_path, csv_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

    # Set up the display window
    cv2.namedWindow('Video with CSV', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    # Read the first frame to get video dimensions
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = frame.shape

    # Calculate the height for the table display
    table_height = int(height * 0.8)

    # Initialize the scrolling position and scrolling step size
    scroll_pos = 0
    scroll_step = int(table_height / 10)  # Adjust the step size as needed

    while True:
        # Read the next frame from the video
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break

        # Get the frame number and corresponding data from the CSV file
        frame_number = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
        data = df.iloc[frame_number - 1]

        # Create a table to display the CSV data
        table = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()

        # Create a blank image to display the table data
        table_image = 255 * np.ones((table_height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

        # Add the table text to the table image
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        font_scale = 0.5
        font_thickness = 1
        text_color = (0, 0, 0)  # Black color

        y_offset = scroll_step
        for i, (col_name, val) in enumerate(table.items()):
            cv2.putText(
                table_image,
                f"{col_name}: {val.values[0]}",
                (10, y_offset),
                font,
                font_scale,
                text_color,
                font_thickness,
                cv2.LINE_AA
            )
            y_offset += scroll_step

        # Display the video frame
        cv2.imshow('Video with CSV', frame)

        # Create a combined image with the video frame and table image
        combined_image = np.vstack((frame, table_image))

        # Display the combined image in the window
        cv2.imshow('Video with CSV', combined_image)

        # Scroll the table if needed
        if frame_number % 30 == 0:  # Adjust the scroll frequency as needed
            scroll_pos += 1

        # Check for user interrupt (press 'q' to exit)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release the video stream and close the display window
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Provide the paths to the video and CSV file
video_path = r"Main.mp4"
csv_path = r"Test_1.csv"

# Call the function to display the video with CSV data
display_video_with_csv(video_path, csv_path)
```

Expected result:
[image]

Actual result:
[image]